# How to insert value to the new table based on condition

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table which has three column

```
A  B  
1  9999

2   999

3    99

4     9
```

Now I need to insert data into the new empty table, the query I am writing for this is below

I want when it insert into the new table it will come like this

```
A  B  
1  9999

2  0999

3  0099

4  0009
```

I am clueless how to do it, please help

Comment: May I know the reason for the down vote?

Comment: You say the table has three columns. Why are you showing us only two?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT
INTO    newtable
VALUES  a, RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(b AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 4)
FROM    oldtable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (A, B)
SELECT A, RIGHT(10000 + B, 4)
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT A, REPLACE(SPACE(4-LEN(B)) & B, ' ', '0')
INTO NewTableName
FROM OldTableName
```